# My cookie reader is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies

So, I can't find any Python 3 scripts online that actually work to read cookies.
Here's the code (explain what is after);

```
red_theme = "red_style.css"
blue_theme = "blue_style.css"
green_theme = "green_style.css"
dark_theme = "dark_style.css"
light_theme = "light_style.css"

### COOKIE WRITER + THEME SETTINGS
jar = Cookie.SimpleCookie()

if data.getvalue("t") == "red":
    theme = red_theme
    jar['s_theme']=red_theme
if data.getvalue("t") == "blue":
    theme = blue_theme
    jar['s_theme']=blue_theme
if data.getvalue("t") == "green":
    theme = green_theme
    jar['s_theme']=green_theme
if data.getvalue("t") == "dark":
    theme = dark_theme
    jar['s_theme']=dark_theme
if data.getvalue("t") == "light":
    theme = light_theme
    jar['s_theme']=light_theme
else:
    theme = red_theme
    jar['s_theme']=red_theme

### COOKIE READER
try:
    jar = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"])
    theme = jar["s_theme"].value
except (Cookie.CookieError, KeyError):
    theme = "error.css"
```

This script finds if you have ?t=***** as a certain theme (red, green, blue... etc.). Then on that info it writes a cookie (jar) as [s_theme = colour]
But... The read script dosen't work.

```
### COOKIE READER
try:
    jar = Cookie.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"])
    theme = jar["s_theme"].value
except (Cookie.CookieError, KeyError):
    theme = "error.css"
```

At the HTML code after; it does this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=\"""" + theme + """\">
```

In summary; trying to make a theme setter that chages the default based on which you picked, so if you went to https://...?theme=dark, it would set your default theme to dark. But... I can't work the read script.

Really would appreciate your help - Reefive

Comment: What is that `Cookie.SimpleCookie`? There's no `Cookie` module in Python 3. There is `http.cookies`, but you're clearly not using that. So what are you using?

Comment: Oh yes forgot to mention, there is `import Cookies, os` at the top of my code

Comment: OK, but `import Cookies` is just going to fail with an `ImportError`., because there is no such module. So either you're not really running Python 3, or you've installed some third-party library you're not telling us about.

Comment: urrgghhh why do I keep on mistyping! I meant `import Cookie` *annoyed loud sigh*

Comment: But there’s _still_ nothing with _that_ name in Python 3. So, again, either you’re not really running Python 3, or you’re using some third-party lib that I can’t even find on PyPI so you’ll have to tell us what it is.